# Why can't I use response.write in fs.readFile?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my code.

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
console.log('Connection');
var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
path = path.substr(1);

switch(path){
    case '':
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
        response.end();
        break;
    case 'socket.html':
        response.write("read file"); //works
        fs.readFile(__dirname + '\\' + path, function(error, data){
            if (error){
                response.writeHead(404); //this doesn't work
            }
            else{
                response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'}); //doesn't work
                response.write("OK"); //doesn't work
            }
        });
        response.end();
        break;
    default:
        response.writeHead(404);
        response.end();
        break;
}
});
```

The server listens on port 8001 and when I visit http://myhost.com:8001/socket.html, I can only see "read file". Methods in response seems like broken in the callback function readFile.
Can somebody tell my why and give me a solution? Thanks!
(Forgive my poor English :)  ).

Comment: Remove the line `response.write("read file")` and try again

Answer (score 4):

You're ending the response too early. The function you pass to readFile is an asynchronous callback, which runs after the whole switch statement.

Comment: Also, what slebtman commented: you can't write anything before the response headers.

Comment: Thanks, I solved this by using readFileSync instead of readFile. Is it OK to use readFileSync? And I wrote exactly the same code as this tutorial(http://www.danielnill.com/blog/nodejs-tutorial-with-socketio/), It seems his using readFile and end response works out just fine.

Comment: Looks like that tutorial is wrong (it's ok for the other `case`s though. And yes, readFileSync is okay.

Comment: @bfavaretto sorry this caused you some issues.  Hopefully the repo for the tutorial will give you an example of how it should work.  https://github.com/DanielNIll/node-and-socket-example

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, @DanielNill! I'll notify the asker.

Comment: @Tongji_WD Take a look at the above comment by Daniel Nill.

Comment: @bfavaretto I was reading the tutorial too. The code on that page doesn't work because fs.readFile is async. Only need to move response.end() inside the switch conditionals